# Not able to display description while sharing application on LinkedIn and Google+

Tags: html, google-plus, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to share my asp.net application on social media Network. Its working fine on Facebook and twitter. 
But for Linkedin and Google+ only showing Image and Title of share.
I have added description in meta data. But its not coming on share block.
Description is added as

```
 <meta property="og:description" 
  content="Sean Connery found fame and fortune as the suave, sophisticated British agent, James Bond." />
```

Anybody having idea how to show description on linkedin and Google+ share.